# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR not working with my pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle10g

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.REZ FROM
(
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_EQUATION, '([A-Z|a-z|0-9]+)\{([0-9|\+|\-| |\*|\/\)\(]+)\}#([A-Z|a-z|0-9|_]+)#',1, LEVEL) AS REZ FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_EQUATION, '([A-Z|a-z|0-9]+)\{([0-9|\+|\-| |\*|\/\)\(]+)\}#([A-Z|a-z|0-9|_]+)#',1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
) A;
```

If I supplied the following input:

```
P_EQUATION := 'A123{(01+02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE# + B123{(20+10)/20}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#';
```

It gives me the following:

```
REZ
-------------------------------------
A123{(01+02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#
B123{(20+10)/20}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#
```

But, although the minus sign is included in the pattern, if I have added it inside the curly brackets, it will not recognize the text anymore as a match!

ex:

```
P_EQUATION := 'A123{(01-02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#';
```

I'm not able to find a solution to this, it is freaking me out, especially, when I tried to match the minus sign alone it works, if I tried to match digits alone it also works :(

Comment: leave aside everything..why are you using `|` in character class? `[A-Za-z0-9]+` alone will work fine

Comment: I don't know, Would it cause any problem ?

Comment: it will match `|` literally if it is there in a string

Comment: Oh, I see, I will fix this later when I know what's wrong with the pattern in the case I described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle appears to be using POSIX style regexes: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm#i690819

> The backslash is NOT a metacharacter in a POSIX bracket expression. So in POSIX, the regular expression `[\d]` matches a `\` or a `d`
>
> > http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

The backslashes are probably messing it up, and they're not necessary. You also don't realize that `|` is a literal inside a char class (which the comments also pointed out). I have fixed these problems, and I moved the `-` to the start of the char class, which allows it to be interpreted as a literal.

Here you go:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)\{([-0-9+ */)(]+)\}#([A-Za-z0-9_]+)#
```

Comment: That worked! thank you. I have tried to remove all the |, but didn't work neither before, the minus sign position in the pattern was kept the same, that's why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't quite figure out the issue with your code but here is one way to do it:

```
with temp as
(
  select 'A123{(01+02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE# + B123{(20+10)/20}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#' P_EQUATION from dual union all
  select 'A123{(01-02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#' P_EQUATION from dual
)

SELECT DISTINCT A.REZ FROM
(
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_EQUATION, '[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+{\([[:digit:]]+\S[[:digit:]]+\)\S[[:digit:]]+}#[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+#',1, LEVEL) AS REZ FROM temp
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_EQUATION, '[[:alpha:]]+[[:digit:]]+{\([[:digit:]]+\S[[:digit:]]+\)\S[[:digit:]]+}#[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+#',1, LEVEL)  IS NOT NULL
) A;
```

OUTPUT:

```
REZ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
---------------------------------------
B123{(20+10)/20}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
A123{(01-02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
A123{(01+02)*2}#ACCOUNT_BALANCE#
```

Comment: Thank you, this is for 11g, my server is 10g